# How to decrease a number with a percentage C#

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game project in Unity. My issue is that I want to take a number and decrease it by a specific percentage. Can I could be pointed to a good resource or provided with a good answer.

Comment: There are innumerable resources available for basic math.

Comment: `var newValue = originalValue * 0.6f;` Just multiply by the percentage (remember, percent is a decimal value where 100% = 1.0, 50% = 0.5 and 05 = 0.0). The formula I just posted will reduce a number to 60% of its value, if you wanted to reduce it *by* 60%, you would use `originalValue * (1.0f - 0.6f)`, or in other words, multiply it by 40%.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's unity?

```
float results = OriginalValue - (OriginalValue * Percent / 100);
```

Comment: Unity 3d... a game engine. unity3d.com or something if intrested.

Comment: @JuhaJGamer, I suspect JerryM was being a tad sarcastic in asking what Unity is, as it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: for me results = value - (value * percent / 100) if having percentage like lets say the 60 it gives me for a number 3895

Comment: @DavidArno, Ya just thought abou that...

Comment: @JuhaJGamer, if your starting value is 6491.67, then 60% of that is indeed 3895.

Comment: I asked about the syntax because I wanted to take a peek at the syntax. I am occasionally sarcastic though.